# Удалить дубликаты строк, оставить только 1-ю строку и посчитать количество

Tags: mysql

В таблице оценок есть идентификатор записи и идентификатор пользователя. Как можно схлопнуть дублирующиеся оценки пользователя для записи, установив значение rank равным сумме всех его оценок для записи?

```
CREATE TABLE Rank (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `postId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `userId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `rank` INT(11) NOT NULL,
);

|------|--------|--------|------|
|  id  | postId | userId | rank |
|------|--------|--------|------|
|  1   |    1   |   1    |   5  |
|  2   |    1   |   2    |   5  |
|  3   |    1   |   1    |   4  |
|  4   |    2   |   2    |   5  |
|  5   |    2   |   1    |   2  |
|  6   |    3   |   1    |   3  |
|  7   |    3   |   1    |   4  |
|------|--------|--------|------|
```

После преобразований:

```
|------|--------|--------|------|
|  id  | postId | userId | rank |
|------|--------|--------|------|
|  1   |    1   |   1    |   9  |
|  2   |    1   |   2    |   5  |
|  4   |    2   |   2    |   5  |
|  5   |    2   |   1    |   2  |
|  6   |    3   |   1    |   7  |
|------|--------|--------|------|
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(id) as id, postId, userId, sum(rank) as rank
  from Rank
 group by postId, userId
```

Что бы изменить данные в таблице исходя из этих условий надо выполнить два запроса, сначала изменить Rank в "первых" записях:

```
update Rank A
 inner join
  (select min(id) as id,userId, postId,sum(rank) as rank
     from Rank
    group by userId, postId) B
    on A.id=B.id
   set A.rank=B.rank
```

После чего удалить лишние записи:

```
delete D.*
  from Rank D
 inner join(
            select id from Rank A
             where exists(select 1 from Rank B where B.postId=A.postId
               and B.userId=A.userId and B.id<A.id)
           ) B
    on D.id=B.id
```

Comment: Спасибо, но этот запрос не удаляет дублирующиеся строки. Он только не показывает их из-за группировки. Мне надо их удалить