# Не работает DELETE запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос который успешно возвращает результат:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_article_tags t1
       WHERE tag_id = '16256'
       AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_article_tags t2
                  WHERE t1.article_id=t2.article_id
                  AND tag_id = '17000')
```

Заменил `SELECT *` на `DELETE`, теперь выбрасывает ошибку:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't1 WHERE tag_id = '16256' ' at line 1
```

Есть у кого идеи почему так?

Comment: Много записей удаляет такой запрос ? И первичный ключ в таблице по каким полям, отдельное поле ID есть ? (это что бы переклеить delete с запросом возвращающим ID записей которые надо удалять, например)

Comment: @Mike цифра может быть порядка 100к записей. первичный ключ полю  id.

Comment: Т.е. за один раз он удалит 100к записей ? ну тогда идея получить список и удалять по нему нерабочая. долго выбирать будет каждую из 100к. тогда как сказал cheops. через join. прямо в условии join ON указывайте `t1.article_id=t2.article_id
                  AND tag_id = '17000'` ведь запись с данным article_id и tag_id=17000 наверняка одна

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в mysql оператор delete не работает с подзапросами

Comment: @user193361 Еще как работает, например как тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543375/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-1-%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE/543376#543376

Comment: @Mike Не совсем понял как должен выглядеть запрос. Вы бы не могли привести пример?

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets Написал ответом. В принципе в голову приходит еще один вариант по типу первого. получение того же списка ID не exists, а за один проход с group by. но все таки интересно сколько за один раз удаляется записей, если действительно 100к то второй вариант мне кажется более жизненным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE A.* FROM tbl_article_tags A
  JOIN (
        SELECT id
          FROM tbl_article_tags t1
         WHERE tag_id = '16256'
           AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_article_tags t2
                       WHERE t1.article_id=t2.article_id
                         AND tag_id = '17000')
       ) B ON A.ID=B.ID
```

Или немного проще:

```
DELETE A.* FROM tbl_article_tags A
  JOIN tbl_article_tags B
    ON B.article_id=A.article_id
   AND B.tag_id = '17000'
 WHERE A.tag_id = '16256'
```

Какой из вариантов окажется быстрее в вашем случае сложно сказать, проверьте

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант

```
DELETE
 FROM tbl_article_tags
       WHERE tag_id = '16256'
       AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_article_tags t2
                  WHERE tbl_article_tags.article_id=t2.article_id
                  AND tag_id = '17000')
```

Comment: выбрасывает ошибку `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbl_article_tags' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: https://ru.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/
при проверке запроса выдает, что составлен корректно, хорошо, сейчас разберемся.

Comment: В MySQL такой вариант не сработает, вы не можете обращаться во вложенном запросе к таблице из которой удаляются данные.

Comment: @cheops хм, странно.. натыкался при поиске на запросы такого типа. Вот к примеру на одном форуме нашел: `DELETE T
FROM Table3 T
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table3 TT WHERE TT.f1=T.f1 AND TT.ID<T.ID);` писали, что он сработал

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets это фишка MySQL, тут удаление курсорное, поэтому такое ограничение. Через самообъединение таблицы если сделаете, через многотабличный DELETE - сработает.

Comment: @cheops благодарю за ответ. Если я правильно понял, самообъединение продублирует каждый столбец. Не будет ли это все выполняться долго? записей в бд очень много. может стоит поискать альтернативные методы решения задачи?